# Cytoscape.js Graph does not run in the nested angular component. Error - Cannot read property 'className' of null

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I am trying to create a separate angular component for a graph built in cytoscape. Now I am trying to use the same component in the other component in Angular but it does not do anything. It also gives me an error Error - Cannot read property 'className' of null

Here is the Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvrntx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata-cytoscape%2Fdata-cytoscape.component.html

Click on graph and open console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [angular-material doc](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)

> Lazy Loading
> By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them into the DOM until the tab is activated

The problem is that `cy` div is not being attached to `DOM` until user activates the tab but `DataCytoscapeComponent` component is getting initialized and trying to access `cy` div which is the cause of the error, To solve this you can `lazy load` `DataCytoscapeComponent` component which will cause the component to not initialize until tab is activated by user.

```
<mat-tab label="Graph">
  <ng-template matTabContent>
    <app-data-cytoscape></app-data-cytoscape>
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

Here the working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-87utgb)

**Note:** Graph was not visible when tab clicked because the `height` is getting set to 0 so i have set default `min-height` in component css and removed `absolute` positioning.